# I get a 404 error on my page. But it works correctly when I refresh the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting a 404 error but the problem is solved when I refresh the page.

This url is being called by a service. In this case it always gets error. If I refresh the page the problem is getting better. The page opens.

Where is the problem? Can you help me?

Callback Parameter:

```
 CallbackUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}{httpContext.Request.PathBase}/company/payment/callbackpayments/?data=" + model.Transaction.Id
```

Action:

```
 [HttpGet]
 public IActionResult CallbackPayment(string token)
 {
     return View();
 }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8I6m.jpg

Comment: have you tried using the browser debugging tools to check for errors there?

Comment: can you try ?token instead of ?data in your link? And remove the / between callbackpayments and ?data

Comment: please share inspect element details for more information. and also please verify SSL is enabled or Not ?

Comment: SSL is enabled, element details is empty.

Comment: Please do not post the same question over and over again on this site. If it's not getting enough attention, revise it to provide more detail and information that can be used to solve the issue. You may also opt to share it to social media or other groups you belong to in order to source answers there.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the `/` is causing the 404 error, and your query parameter is incorrect change `?data` to `?token` so when it does hit the value will be set.

Current

`CallbackUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}{httpContext.Request.PathBase}/company/payment/callbackpayments/?data=" + model.Transaction.Id`

Should be

`CallbackUrl = $"{httpContext.Request.Scheme}://{httpContext.Request.Host}{httpContext.Request.PathBase}/company/payment/callbackpayments?token=" + model.Transaction.Id`

Comment: I tried it that way. The problem still continues.

Comment: [Authorize(Roles = "Company")]
    [Area("company")]
    public class PaymentController : Controller

Comment: @burakramazan how are you redirecting to this route?

Comment: I click the reload button in the browser